# What happens if you have a table in subquery with same alias as same table in outer query?

Tags: sql-server

Working on a somewhat large query trying to improve performance.  One thing I found is that there is a spot with a subquery, but the inner query has the same table as the outer query, with the same alias.  Is this defined behavior?

```
select * from documents d
left join ( select distinct d.id, 'Yes' as 'IsCertainType' from documents d
    left join documentAttributes da on d.id = da.id where da.Description like '%CertainType%'
    ) #certainType
on d.Id = #certainType.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

It is fine as the inner and outer queries have different scopes

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for the subquery at all. Just do the `Left JOIN` and be done with it.

```
    select distinct d.id, 'Yes' as 'IsCertainType' 
    from documents d
    left join documentAttributes da 
    on d.id = da.id
    where da.Description like '%CertainType%'
```

OR As stated in my comment if other rows with the same id in table documents has different values than the returned row by distinct, you can do `GROUP BY`

```
    select d.id, d.someColum, etc. 'Yes' as 'IsCertainType' 
    from documents d
    left join documentAttributes da 
    on d.id = da.id
    where da.Description like '%CertainType%'
    GROUP BY d.id, d.someColumn, etc..
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just coming to that conclusion.  The actual subquery had a bunch of commented out stuff that makes it look like this subquery might have been necessary at some point but after I got rid of all the clutter, I was like "this is just a d*** left join"

Comment: @Kevin Unless of course you need more information than `id` from table `documents` as in your example they are doing a `SELECT *`, you can always modify my answer to include other columns of table `documents`. The `distinct` bothers me a bit, because if other columns of rows with the same `id` have different values, you may lose data which you want, if that is the case, I'd suggest removing `distinct` and doing a `GROUP BY`